Taking derivative with respect to quantum canonical ensemble expectation value
Let's say I have a Hamiltonian operator $H(x_a..)$, where $x_a,x_b$ are some parameters of my Hamiltonian.
I can calculate the quantum canonical ensemble expectation value of $\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_a}$ (this is also an operator)
$$\left\langle \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_a} \right\rangle= \frac{Tr\left[\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_a}\exp(-\beta H )\right]}{Tr\left[\exp(-\beta H)\right]}$$
If I want to take derivative of this expectation value
$$\partial_{x_b}\left\langle \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_a} \right\rangle\sim \frac{Tr\left[\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_a}\partial x_b\exp(-\beta H )\right]}{Tr\left[\exp(-\beta H)\right]}$$
where the $\sim$ means containing. Long story short, I think the standard strategy here is to decompose $exp(-\beta H)$ in the numerator into $(\exp(-\beta H/N))^N$, where N is some extremely large number. Then by making use of the cyclic property of the trace, we would arrive at the final expression for the above term
$$\partial_{x_b}\left\langle \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_a} \right\rangle\sim \int_{0}^{\beta} d\tau \langle \exp(-H \tau) \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_a} \exp(H \tau) \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_b}\rangle$$
A crucial step in deriving this expression would be the following arguement: since N is extremely large, then $\exp(-\beta H/N)$ is almost like a scalar, so
$$\partial_{x_b}  \exp(-\beta H/N)\approx -\exp(-\beta H/N) (\frac{\beta}{N})(\partial_{x_b} H) $$
My question is, what is the strict justification for the last step? How to prove that the error incurred in doing so is suppressed by some powers of N?

Why can't you simply use the chain rule here? If you calculate traces in the eigenbasis of the Hamiltoniann, it is indistinguishable from the classical case. Am I wrong?

@RogerV. It is not the same as the classical case, due to commutation issues. The classical case, it would be just correlation, but in the quantum case, you need imaginary time ordering. Developing in a basis makes it a bit harder to recognise.

@LPZ imaginary time ordering is needed for perturbation treatment - the first equations (as written) does not seem to require such complications - it is a simple thermodynamic average.

On a side note, you can avoid the Trotter formula by using instead the standard interaction picture (if you are already familiar with it from previous QM courses). I will write $\partial_{x_i} = \partial_i$. At linear order you can write:
$$
H(x_i+dx_i) = H(x_i)+\partial_iH(x_i)dx_i
$$
so that $H(x_i)$ is the unperturbed hamiltonian and $\partial_iH(x_i)dx_i$ is the perturbation. Thus, when computing the evolution operator in the interaction picture (imaginary time):
$$
\begin{align}
e^{-\beta H(x_i+dx_i)} &= \mathcal T\exp\left(-dx_i\int_0^\beta e^{-\tau H(x_i)}\partial_iH(x_i)e^{\tau H(x_i)}d\tau\right)e^{-\beta H(x_i)}\\
&= \left(1-dx_i\int_0^\beta e^{-\tau H(x_i)}\partial_iH(x_i)e^{\tau H(x_i)}+o(dx_i)\right)e^{-\beta H(x_i)}
\end{align}
$$
so you identify:
$$
\partial_ie^{-\beta H} =  -\left(\int_0^\beta e^{-\tau H}\partial_iHe^{\tau H}d\tau \right)e^{-\beta H}
$$
This approach is useful to systematically compute higher order derivatives of the exponential.
You therefore get:
$$
\partial_b\operatorname{Tr}\left(\partial_aHe^{-\beta H}\right) = \operatorname{Tr}\left(\partial_{ab}^2He^{-\beta H}\right)- \operatorname{Tr}\left[\left(\int_0^\beta \partial_aH e^{-\tau H}\partial_bHe^{\tau H}d\tau \right)e^{-\beta H}\right]
$$
and so:
$$
\partial_b\langle\partial_a H\rangle = \langle\partial^2_{ab}H\rangle-\beta\left(\frac1\beta\int_0^\beta\left\langle \partial_aH e^{-\tau H}\partial_bHe^{\tau H}\right\rangle d\tau-\langle\partial_a H\rangle\langle\partial_b H\rangle\right)
$$
The first term is the usual mean of the derivative. The second term can be interpreted as a quantum version of the covariance, with the first term corresponding to the time average of the time ordered correlation. Indeed, just the classical covariance would be ambiguous due to the non equivalent orderings if $H,\partial_aH,\partial_bH$ do not commute. The full derivation shows that imaginary time ordering is the correct way to go.
You can use the same approach to get a formula in the first place for the mean derivative:
$$
\partial_a\ln Z = -\beta\langle\partial_aH\rangle \\
Z = \operatorname{Tr}e^{-\beta H}
$$
Viewing $\ln Z$ as a cumulant generating function, this explains the covariance interpretation and why $\partial_b\langle\partial_a H\rangle$ is symmetric.

+1. The paper "Exponential Operators and Parameter Differentiation in Quantum Physics" by Wilcox (and references therein) might be of interest.


$$\partial_{x_b}  \exp(-\beta H/N)\approx -\exp(-\beta H/N) (\frac{\beta}{N})(\partial_{x_b} H) $$
My question is, what is the strict justification for the last step? How to prove that the error incurred in doing so is suppressed by some powers of N?

$$
\partial_{x}  \exp(-\beta H/N) = \frac{-\beta}{N}\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} + (-\frac{\beta}{N})^2\frac{1}{2!}
\left(H\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}H 
\right)+ \ldots
$$
$$
=\frac{-\beta}{N}\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} + (-\frac{\beta}{N})^2\frac{1}{2!}
\left(2H\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}+[\frac{\partial H}{\partial x},H ]
\right)+ \ldots
$$
$$
=\frac{-\beta}{N}\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}-\frac{-\beta}{N}H\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} +\frac{\beta}{2N} [H,\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}]\right)+ \ldots
$$
$$
=\frac{-\beta}{N}\left(e^{-\beta H/N}\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}+\frac{\beta}{2N}[H,\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}]\right)+ \ldots
$$
$$
=\frac{-\beta}{N}e^{-\beta H/N}\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} + O(1/N^2)
$$
$$
=\frac{-\beta}{N}\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}e^{-\beta H/N} + O(1/N^2)\;.
$$

IMHO the OP is mislead by a recourse to imaginary time... which is not warranted here. Indeed, let us assume that we know the exact eigenstates of $H$:
$$
H|n\rangle = E_n|n\rangle,
$$
(these coule be many-body eigenstates, and index $nn$ might include the particle number - see any discussion of Lehmannn representation for a more detailed notation.)
Then the partition function is given by:
$$
Z = \text{Tr}e^{-\beta H}=\sum_ne^{-\beta E_n},$$
hence
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\log Z = 
\frac{\sum_ne^{-\beta E_n}(-\beta)\frac{\partial E_n}{\partial x}}{\sum_ne^{-\beta E_n}}=
-\beta \frac{\sum_n\langle n|e^{-\beta H}|n\rangle\frac{\partial \langle n|H|n\rangle}{\partial x}}{\text{Tr}e^{-\beta H}}=\\
-\beta \frac{\sum_n\langle n|e^{-\beta H}|n\rangle\langle n|\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}|n\rangle}{\text{Tr}e^{-\beta H}}=
-\beta \frac{\sum_{n,m}\langle n|e^{-\beta H}|m\rangle\langle m|\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}|n\rangle}{\text{Tr}e^{-\beta H}}=
-\beta \frac{\text{Tr}\left[e^{-\beta H}\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}\right]}{\text{Tr}e^{-\beta H}}
$$
One can likewise calculate other derivatives.

@LPZ my only slight doubt here is about $\partial_x\langle n|H|n\rangle = \langle n| \partial_x H|n\rangle$.

That should be true due to the Hellmann-Feynman theorem, no?

I agree with what you wrote, there is no need for time ordering. However, I think that the OP does not want to compute the first order moments/derivatives, but rather the second order moments/derivatives. In the latter case, your last remark "likewise" is a bit bold, because the formulas will get a lot messier in the basis expansion. Plus, you will not be saved by the Hellmann-Feynmann theorem. See my answer for example for the final formula which requires time ordering
